# load view using constant in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I want to load view using constant in codeigniter , just by  printing constant view should be loaded . Is it possible in **codeigniter**?

```
define('SEARCH_POP_START_TAG',$this->load->view('templates/search_pop_start_tag.php'));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to return your view as a String, see the [View documentation](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html#returning-views-as-data) with returning views as data. Not sure if defining a view as a constant is the best architecture though.

As in:

```
$string = $this->load->view('myfile', '', TRUE);
```